# How can I add entire Array of structures into mysql database using GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

```
db.AutoMigrate(&student.Student{})
db.AutoMigrate(&address.Address{})
db.AutoMigrate(&subject.Subject{})
user := student.Student{

    Adresses: []address.Address{
        {City: "mum", State: "india", Country: "jjm", Pincode: "5859"},
        {City: "muk", State: "inia", Country: "ojm", Pincode: "5779"},
        {City: "pum", State: "rindia", Country: "8jm", Pincode: "6159"},
        {City: "rum", State: "ljndia", Country: "hjm", Pincode: "1459"},
    }, Subs: []subject.Subject{
        subject.Subjects[0], subject.Subjects[1], subject.Subjects[2],
    },
}
```

I want to Add this structure into mysql DB but when I run the update query only the 1st element of the array is updated in the database I want all the elements to be pushed in that db can you help me on this??

Function I used for update

```
func Testupdate(n int, st student.Student) {
dsn := "root:Pranav@18@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/students_data?charset=utf8&parseTime=True"
db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
}
db.AutoMigrate(&student.Student{})
db.AutoMigrate(&address.Address{})
db.AutoMigrate(&subject.Subject{})
var sd student.Student
db.First(&sd, n)
db.Model(&sd).Update("Adresses", st.Adresses)
db.Model(&sd).Update("Subs", st.Subs)

db.Save(&sd)}
```

Comment: It would help if you could post the entire code. You can put the entire program on Go Playground and share the link in your question. For example, what type are you actually passing to the function: an array or an instance of Student?

Answer (score 0):

Use gormv2 [batch add](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Batch-Insert)

It has a batch add option for this purpose